# Does 1000 tables per query limit apply to partitioned tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I know that this limit applies when I query 1000 different tables, but Firebase Analytics exports its events to single partitioned table named 'app_events_*'.

A new partition is automatically created each day. I will have 1000 partitions of this table if I track events for 2 years and 269-270 days.

It's not clear to me if I can use wildcard in my query and use more than 1000 partitions of same partitioned table (more than 1000 days of data).

What exactly happens in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a partitioned table. You can read about partitioned tables [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables). [Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables), which are what you are using, let you query multiple tables at once, and the same 1000 tables per query limit applies as if you had unioned then explicitly in the query.